# Calling a Python function without parentheses

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, is there a way to call a function without parentheses?

like

```
account.add 3000
```

I want to code a quick app and use it on a Python shell window, and I think it should save time to input values without those parentheses.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: "and use it on a command-line window" Then you aren't running Python, you run user/standard input. You must interpret that anyway. How are you interpreting input right now to get it to run Python code?

Comment: Consider using `property` with `setter`, which can simplify your pair of parentheses into an equal sign.

Comment: `account` could be an instance of a class with a "property" called `balance`, in which case `account.balance += 3000` could call the property's "setter" function. Properties can also have "getter" method that will be call whenever their current value is read. Here's some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property). It's all based on Python descriptors - see [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=property).

Comment: In `Python2`, `print` was a keyword rather than a function, so you could write either `print 'hello world'` or `print('hello world')`. That's the only case I can imagine at the moment for the syntax you mentioned. I've never heard of an option to add keywords or C-like macros in Python

Comment: @MisterMiyagi : I mean "Pyhon shell".

Comment: @MechanicPig : equal signs still take some time if I call the function repeatly.

Comment: 'I mean "Pyhon shell".' You might be better off just using a different shell, then. For example, IPython has `%autocall` which makes `operator.add 1, 2` evaluate to 3.

Comment: Also, IPython has autocompletion, which is likely to save you way more time than by not typing two chars

Comment: @norok2 autocompletion is not important since I am going to import all the code I need. I just want to use the shell as a simple user interface to input value with keyboard to database or api.

Comment: Autocompletion includes things such as adding parentheses for you.

Comment: @norok2 Python shell has autocompletion too. And unlike IPython, it actually gives you the first parenthesis, so in IPython you have to type one character more...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `eval` function in python to convert a string to a function call:

```
def fun(function, value):
    eval(function + f'({value})')

def add(value):
    x = value
    print(x)

x,y = input().split()

fun(x,y)
```

Here we take x and y as inputs from the user.
x denotes the function to be called and y acts as the parameter.
Then we simply call `eval` and passing it a string to evaluate consisting of the function call as it was with parenthesis.

You can simply put this code in an infinite loop to be able to continuously evaluate functions in this way.